# Intersecting of Hypergraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am beginner for studying hypergraph, I learn hypergraph from this [site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) but it still not enough for me to understand about hypergraph (especially for intersecting  hypergraph).

> The hypergraph $G$ is t-intersecting if every two edges of $G$ have at least $t$ vertices in common.

Anyone can give example of 2-intersecting and 3-intersecting ? As well as references to learn about hypergraph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $r\gt\frac t2,$ the hypergraph $K_{2r-t}^r$ (all $r$-element subsets of a $(2r-t)$-element set) is $t$-intersecting.

You can learn more about hypergraphs from the text [*Hypergraphs: Combinatorics of Finite Sets*](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Oktatas/Algoritmusok-hatekonysaga/Berge-hypergraphs.pdf) by [Claude Berge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Berge).